# Ants profiler is not showing the results

Tags: c#, windows, ants

I am using the ants profiler to see performance problems. I have compiled my windows application in release mode and started the Ants profiler, but once I click the stop profiler, I can't see any results. Is there anything that needs to be done?

Answer (score 2):

There're a few things that can cause this problem: have you tried the suggestions in Red Gate's support center for "[Troubleshooting missing results](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content?p=ANTS%20Performance%20Profiler&c=ANTS_Performance_Profiler/help/6.3/troubleshooting_missing_results.htm&toc=ANTS_Performance_Profiler/help/6.3/toc1447550.htm)"?

That suggests looking at the following possibilities:

- Missing PDB files - either because you don't have them for the profiled code, or they're not stored in the expected directory and ANTS can't find them
- No available managed code to profile - either because you're trying to profile on a remote machine, are profiling methods exclusively comprising unmanaged code, or are profiling something where no method contributes more than 1% of total CPU time
- Unreadable performance counters - in which case rebuilding the performance counters will usually help.